# I should to define property or a function for a calculation field in a class in android?

Tags: java, android

I use a myListVideo to store Video class, I use two different way to define class Video (Method 1 and Method 2),

If I use Method 1, I think myListVideo will occupy many memory.

If I use Method 2, I think myListVideo will not occupy many memory, only need to spend a time to invoke function FullFileName() to get full filename .

Right?

**Method 1**

```
List<Video> myListVideo=new Arraylist();
...
for(Video mVideo: mListVideo){
  String s=mVideo.fullFileName; 
}


public class Video {
    public String fullFileName;
    public String fileName;


    public Video(String filename){       
        this.fileName=filename;
        this.fullFileName=mGetVideoArg.videoFolder+"/"+filename;
    }
}
```

**Method 2**

```
List<Video> myListVideo=new Arraylist();
...
for(Video mVideo: mListVideo){
  String s=mVideo.FullFileName(); 
}


public class Video {
    public String fullFileName;

    public Video(String filename){       
        this.fileName=filename;

    }

    public String FullFileName(){
        return  this.fullFileName=mGetVideoArg.videoFolder+"/"+filename;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont see the difference between two methods - both classes have String as member -

Comment: Why do you think that method1 will consume more memory than method2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [Android performance tips](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/articles/perf-tips.html#GettersSetters) I suggest you to use `method1`; define a field and access the field directly.

Now, looking your code I can see that the difference between those two Video classes is just a String (`fullFileName`). If your concern is the memory, the difference in the memory allocation will be determined by the size of the string itself. In this case the memory needed in an extreme case of 100chars wil be [like](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/string_memory_usage.shtml):

`8 x (int) ((((100) x 2) + 45) / 8) = 238 ~ 248 bytes.`

So, If you have 1000 videos and use `method1` your 'extra' space will be like 242kb, but you will gain on speed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes method 1 is wrong it will consume way much memory.
However you can use method 2 which is better in this case.

And yes one suggestion when you are working with pojo classes do not use constructor to set the value to variable. it is not quite recommended instead create a setter-getter method and use that.